# which minimap should I use with custom image in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm using leafletjs with a custom large image where I am serving the tiles from my local server.

I need to display a minimap that shows what is currently visible on screen, what would be best to use in these circumstances?

Is there something already available in leafletjs or do I need to use a plugin or build a custom one?

I saw this one but it seems kind of specific to using a map: https://github.com/Norkart/Leaflet-MiniMap

Comment: You're saying you are using `L.ImageOverlay`, or your image is actually just a `L.TileLayer`?

Comment: I'm using L.TileLayer

Comment: I don't see why the plugin you mentioned would not work then - why issues do you see with it?